# Django: using the URL request as the name of a model's field

Tags: python, django

I used to use the URL request as the name of the function to be executed. For example, supposing the request is `http://localhost:8000/rango/addMember/`, then the function to be executed would be `addMember`. The can be achieved by:

```
def rango(request, funcName):
    ...
    eval(funcName)(request)
    ...
    return render(request, some.html, someContext)

def addMember(request):
    ...
```

That is, the function to call is determined at run time to avoid the following awkward arrangement (supposing there are tens of functions):

```
if funcName=='addMember':
    addMember(request)
elif funcName=='deleteMember':
    deleteMember(request)
...
```

I wonder if there is a similar way to determine the field of a model at run time as follows:

```
class Word(models.Model):
    name = CharField()
    adv = BooleanField()
    adj = BooleanField()
    noun = BooleanField()
    ...

def rango(request, fieldName):
    word = Word.objects.get(...)
    word.eval(fieldName) = True
    ...
```

Django will complaint about the statement `word.eval(fieldName)` not having such an attribute as `eval`.

Comment: Why are you not using url mappings?

Comment: Sorry, but how do I do that? Thanks.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/

Comment: I got it. But I would like to avoid such verbose mappings. Since the request is exactly the function, why list all of them? In my case, there are more 40 of them. In addition, my question is to determine the field, not the function, at run time.

Comment: Because using `eval` is very bad practice. And yes, I know it's not your main question, that's why I only posted a comment :)

Comment: Thanks a lot mattm. But I really like to know why it is a bad practice (if so, I would definitely dump it). Would you elaborate more?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63532/discussion-between-yltang52-and-mattm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [getattr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) and [setattr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr) to access an attribute using a variable name.

In your case, it would be:

```
word = Word.objects.get(...)
setattr(word, fieldName, True)
```